# How to count lines if only the first 6 characters is different?

Tags: arrays, powershell, count, lines

I have a txt file like this:

```
ksakks ...... ......
ksakks ...... ......
ksakks ...... ......
ksakks ...... ......
ksakks ...... ......
ksakks ...... ......
bccscd ...... ......
bccscd ...... ......
bccscd ...... ......
bccscd ...... ......
...
```

I have to count the lines. For example: `ksakks` has 6 lines, `bccscd` has only 4. And if some of them have less than 3, then I have to save their "name", if there are more, then I have to save their "name" in an array.

How can I do that?

Comment: there's the help for formatting your text, also the goal is not entirely clear. what have you tried, what doesn't work?

Comment: `gc file.txt|group {$_.Substring(0,6)} -NoElement|? Count -lt 3|% Name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Select-Sting` to extract your text and then a `Group-Object` to do the counting. Something like this:

```
(Select-String .\yourfile.txt -Pattern '^.{6}' ).Matches | Select -ExpandProperty value | Group-Object | Select Name, Count
```

Comment: Thank you!
It is my bad, I forgot about one thing: in the first parameter, the user has to type a value (like: "Linear algebra"), and only the lines containing the "Linear algebra" has to be count, and after THAT I have to use your code. 
Your code is working but with this it counts the all txt files, not only the ones that includes the first parameter.

Sorry I didn't mention that, I thought I could do it if you help a bit, but I cant rewrite your advice.

Comment: @GiuseppeTheDreamer Add a filter to select just matching lines before grouping them. Please do some legwork yourself. SO is not a place where people provide you with turnkey solutions for your problems.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the count use the below:

```
Get-Content "E:\Source_Test\file.txt"|Group-Object {$PSItem.Substring(0,6)} -NoElement
```

I created a sample file with your data and it came properly. Below are the screenshots for your reference.

**Output:**

[image]

**Text File**

[image]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$result = get-content C:\temp\result.txt | 
                             group { $_.substring(0, 6)} | 
                                                where Count -lt 3 | 
                                                              select Name
```

if your file always have space separator you can do this too

```
$result = import-csv "C:\temp\result.txt"  -Delimiter " " -Header h1 | group h1 | where Count -lt 3 | select Name
```